# Directory copying?

Tags: php

I need to copy some directories with PHP, so I did a few searches and found a few scripts to try, considering that there is no built in method in PHP. I ran one of them and got an error about the maximum running time of the script being exceeding. Thinking this was because some of the files were too big, I increased that time. Little did I know, the script was recursively copying the directory and then copying it inside itself... I'm still in the process of deleting everything it made...

Anyway, I was hoping someone on here would have a reliable script they've written or know about for this type of thing.

edit: hadn't occurred to me that copying a directory to inside itself wasn't a good idea. Sorry whoever wrote the code I just trashed.

Comment: Did you try this: http://codestips.com/php-copy-directory-from-source-to-destination/ ? Looks OK to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
   function copy_directory($source, $destination, $whatsgoingon = false){
      if ($destination{strlen($destination) - 1} == '/'){
         $destination = substr($destination, 0, -1);
        }
      if (!is_dir($destination)){
         if ($whatsgoingon){
            echo "Creating directory {$destination}\n";
            }
         mkdir($destination, 0755);
      }

      $folder = opendir($source);

      while ($item = readdir($folder)){
         if ($item == '.' || $item == '..'){
            continue;
            }
         if (is_dir("{$source}/{$item}")){
            copy_dir("{$source}/{$item}", "{$destination}/{$item}", $whatsgoingon);
         }else{
            if ($whatsgoingon){
               echo "Copying {$item} to {$destination}"."\n";
            }
            copy("{$source}/{$item}", "{$destination}/{$item}");
            }
      }
   }
?>
```

You can use:

```
copy_directory('./directory', './directory2/'); // copy the directory

copy_directory('./directory', './'); // copy the files to the same directory

copy_directory('./directory', './directory2/', true);
// Show these messages:
// Creating directory ./directory2
// Copying word.docx to ./directory2
// Copying test.txt to ./directory2
```